# Unable to send and receive emails in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, magento-cron, email-scheduler

I have configured cronjob here is the code in crontab

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php-7.1 /var/www/html/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/html/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php-7.1 /var/www/html/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/var/log/update.cron.log
*/8 * * * * /usr/bin/php-7.1 /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Also run command `php bin/magento cron:run`

But unable to receive emails

after debugging I found some file in var folder
here is some message

```
"php_settings_verified": {
            "responseType": "success",
            "data": {
                "xdebug_max_nesting_level": {
                    "message": "Your current setting of xdebug.max_nesting_level=201.\n                 Magento 2 requires it to be set to 200 or more.\n                 Edit your config, restart web server, and try again.",
                    "error": false
                },
                "memory_limit": {
                    "message": "",
                    "error": false,
                    "warning": false
                }
            }
        }
```

which I found may be issue but I already edit php.ini with suggested value .

Please suggest

Comment: I suggest to install this https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler, to make sure you have the crons running . Than debug for other options regarding server.

Comment: @YlgenGuxholli the AOE_Scheduler is for Magento 1 only. Shame there is no version for M2 as it's a great tool.

Comment: @BareFeet my bad sorry, try this instead https://github.com/shockwavemk/magento2-module-cron-schedule

Comment: Uuuu very nice. I think I will give it a go too!